# Costruct a 2x2 matrix that expresses this transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

[image]

A transformation such as $P=P^{2}$ is a projection,  so tr = 1.
This is the system i build in order to calculate the matrix, **the problem it's that it misses an equation and i don't know how to find it**...

$\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\ c &d 
\end{bmatrix}$ is the matrix

$\begin{align*}a+d=1\\
a-2b=0\\
c-2d = 0
\end{align*}$

The last 2 equations is calculated using the kernel.

Comment: You get two more equations by examining the fixed points of $P$, i.e., the line $y=2x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check the condition

> $P$ maps the entire plane onto the line $y = 2x$

it's enough to check it for the basis vectors: that $P e_1$ and $Pe_2$ lie on the line $y=2x$. Since $Pe_1$ and $Pe_2$ are just the columns of $P$, this gives us the equations
\begin{align}
   c &= 2a, \\
   d &= 2b.
\end{align}

To check the condition

> P maps the line $y = -2x$ into the origin

it's enough to check that one point on this line is mapped to the origin, which as you've found gives the condition
\begin{align}
   a - 2b &= 0, \\ c - 2d &=0.
\end{align}
Altogether, this tells us that
$$
   P = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}a & \frac12a \\ 2a & a\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Now we need some way of testing that $P^2 = P$. In fact we can just compute $P^2$ and see for which value of $a$ it equals $P$. You're also right that asking for the trace to be $1$ (and therefore $a = \frac12$) would work. We could also ask that a vector already on the line $y=2x$ is mapped to itself.

Comment: Thanks so much. I dont know why my question got downvoted...